# php html return only one set of data records when clicking the view button

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I need my system to show only the set of 'minutes' a user clicks on and not every set of minutes that the current user is involved in.

At the minute when I click the 'image' to view a set of minutes it prints out each set of minutes that user is involved in, I need it to only print out and be able to edit that one specific set of minutes...  the edit function works but I just need it to print out what the user clicks on and not every set..PLEASE Can ANYONE help with this I have spent all day and don't understand how to get this to work.

Below is the code that shows the php and query in the minutes.php page, when you click the image for 'view' it takes you to the 'viewstudentminutes.php' page, I only want it to print out the minutes you click on not every set.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    if (!(isset($_SESSION["sess_username"]))) header ("Location: index.php");
    $currentUser=$_SESSION["sess_username"];    


$dbQuery = $db->prepare("select * from minute where '$currentUser'=B_number ");
$dbQuery->execute();

$numMinutes = $dbQuery->rowCount();

echo "<p>There are $numMinutes sets of minutes in the system</p>";

$oddRow=true;
while ($dbRow = $dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $ID       = $dbRow['ID'];
    $B_number = $dbRow['B_number'];
    $Date  = $dbRow['Date'];
    $Time  = $dbRow['Time'];
    $Discussion = $dbRow['Discussion'];
    $Actions = $dbRow['Actions'];
    $Dateofnextmeeting = $dbRow['Dateofnextmeeting'];
    $Status = $dbRow['Status'];
    $E_number = $dbRow['E_number'];
    $Supervisor_comments = $dbRow['Supervisor_comments'];


    if ($oddRow) $rowClass="odd"; else $rowClass="even";
    $oddRow=!$oddRow;

    if (isset($_POST['editMinuteID']) && $_POST['editMinuteID']==$ID) {
        echo "<tr class='$rowClass '>
              <form style='display:inline' method='post' action='minutes.php'>
                <input type='hidden' name='editCommitID' value='$ID'>
                <td><input type='varchar' name='editB_number' value='$B_number'></td>
                <td><input type='date' name='editDate' value='$Date'></td>
                <td><input type='time' name='editTime' value='$Time'></td>
                <td><input type='text' name='editDiscussion' value='$Discussion'></td>
                <td><input type='text' name='editActions' value='$Actions'> </td>
                <td><input type='date' name='editDateofnextmeeting'  value='$Dateofnextmeeting'></td>
                <td><input type='enum' name='editStatus' value='$Status'> </td>
                <td><input type='varchar' name='editE_number' value='$E_number'></td>
                <td><input type='text' name='editSupervisor_comments' value='$Supervisor_comments'></td>
                <td colspan='2'><input type='image' src='edit.png'>
             </form>
             </tr>";      
    } else {

        echo "<tr class='$rowClass'><td>$B_number</td><td>$Date</td> <td>$Time</td><td>$Discussion</td><td>$Actions</td><td>$Dateofnextmeeting</td> <td>$Status</td><td>$E_number</td><td>$Supervisor_comments</td>
        echo "<tr class='$rowClass'><td>$B_number</td><td>$Date</td><td>$Time</td><td>$Discussion</td><td>$Actions</td><td>$Dateofnextmeeting</td><td>$Status</td><td>$E_number</td><td>$Supervisor_comments</td>
                  <td class='operation'>
                     <form class='display:inline' method='post' action='viewstudentminutes.php'>
                     <input type='hidden' name='editMinute_ID' value='$ID'>
                     <input type='image' src='edit.png' style='padding-top:7px'>
                     </form></td>
                  <td class='operation'>
                     <form class='display:inline' method='post'  action='minutes.php'   
                           onsubmit='return confirm(\"Are you sure?\")'>
                     <input type='hidden' name='deleteMinuteID' value='$ID'>
                     <input type='image' src='delete.png' style='padding-top:7px'>
                     </form></td>
                     <td class='operation'>
                     <form class='display:inline' method='post' action='viewstudentminutes.php'   
                           onsubmit='viewstudentminutes.php'>
                     <input type='image' src='view.png' style='padding-top:7px'>

                     </form></td>
              </tr>";
    }         
}


?>
```

Below is the code for the 'viewstudentminutes.php' when trying to edit the set of minutes

```
<h2>Minutes</h2>
<table class="table table-condensed">
<?php 


$dbQuery= $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Minute` WHERE `B_number` = '" .     $currentUser . "' AND `id` = " . $_POST['Minute_ID']);
$dbQuery->execute();


$oddRow=true;
while ($dbRow = $dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $ID       = $dbRow['ID'];
    $B_number = $dbRow['B_number'];
    $Date  = $dbRow['Date'];
    $Time  = $dbRow['Time'];
    $Discussion = $dbRow['Discussion'];
    $Actions = $dbRow['Actions'];
    $Dateofnextmeeting = $dbRow['Dateofnextmeeting'];
    $Status = $dbRow['Status'];
    $E_number = $dbRow['E_number'];
    $Supervisor_comments = $dbRow['Supervisor_comments'];


    if ($oddRow) $rowClass="odd"; else $rowClass="even";
    $oddRow=!$oddRow;

    if (isset($_POST['editMinuteID']) && $_POST['editMinuteID']==$id) {
        echo "<tr class='$rowClass'>
              <form style='display:inline' method='post' action='viewstudentminutes.php'>
                <input type='hidden' name='editCommitID' value='$ID'>
                 <tr><td colspan='2'><input type='image' src='edit.png'>    </tr>
                 <tr><th>BNumber</th><td><input type='varchar' name='editB_number' value='$B_number'></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Date</th><td><input type='date' name='editDate' value='$Date'></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Time</th><td><input type='time' name='editTime' value='$Time'></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Discussion</th><td><input type='text' name='editDiscussion' value='$Discussion'></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Actions</th><td><input type='text' name='editActions' value='$Actions'></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Date of Next Meeting</th><td><input type='date' name='editDateofnextmeeting' value='$Dateofnextmeeting'></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Status</th><td><input type='enum' name='editStatus' value='$Status'></td></tr>
                <tr><th>E Number</th><td><input type='varchar' name='editE_number' value='$E_number'></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Supervisor Comments</th><td><input type='text' name='editSupervisor_comments' value='$Supervisor_comments'></td></tr>

             </form>
             </tr>";      
    } else {
        echo "<tr class='$rowClass'>
                <td class='operation'>
                     <form class='display:inline' method='post' action='viewstudentminutes.php'>
                     <input type='hidden' name='editMinute_ID' value='$ID'>
                     <input type='image' src='edit.png' style='padding-top:7px'>
                     </form></td>
                <tr><th>BNumber</th><td>$B_number</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Date</th><td>$Date</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Time</th><td>$Time</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Discussion</th><td>$Discussion</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Actions</th><td>$Actions</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Date of Next Meeting</th><td>$Dateofnextmeeting</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Status</th><td>$Status</td></tr>
                <tr><th>E Number</th><td>$E_number</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Supervisor Comments</th><td>$Supervisor_comments</td></tr>
              </tr>";
    }         
}

?>
</table>
```

The Minute table within the database holds the following fields...

```
1   ID   Primary    int(10)             AUTO_INCREMENT  
2   B_number    varchar(15) latin1_swedish_ci       
3   Date    date            
4   Time    time            
5   Discussion  text    latin1_swedish_ci
6   Actions text    latin1_swedish_ci               
7   Dateofnextmeeting   date             
8   Status  enum('Submitted', 'Approved', 'Rejected', '')   latin1_swedish_ci       
9   Supervisor_comments text    latin1_swedish_ci       
10  E_number    varchar(15) latin1_swedish_ci
```

Please help :(

Comment: Can you post a quick overview of your DB table?

Comment: @Milkmannetje does that help? its a mysql phpmyadmin database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few variables that I'm unsure of what they are - updating your question to include what `$currentUser` is would help.

That said, the issue may be in your SQL statement:

```
$db->prepare("select * from minute where '$currentUser'=B_number ");
```

You are selecting where `$currentUser` is equal to `B_number`. But in your database schema, you show that `B_number` is a column.

I'd try this SQL statement instead:

```
$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Minute` WHERE `B_number` = '" . $currentUser . "' AND `id` = " . $yourIDVariable );
```

**Edit**

Your `viewstudentminutes.php` will iterate over every record returned in your SQL query. You need to uniquely identify your `Minute` record to show just one on your `viewstudentminutes.php` page. You access this page via clicking on an `<img>` tag. But you never send data for which `Minute` object you want with this form. You could add this via:

```
<form class='display:inline' method='post' action='viewstudentminutes.php' onsubmit='viewstudentminutes.php'>
    <input type='image' src='view.png' style='padding-top:7px'>
    <input type='hidden' name='minute_id' value='" . $ID . "'>
</form>
```

Then access this on your `viewstudentminutes.php` as

```
$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Minute` WHERE `B_number` = '" . $currentUser . "' AND `id` = " . $_POST['minute_id']);
```

Comment: yea I have a session_start() at the top of my pages to differentiate between users as a student and supervisor will be able to view these minutes.... the sql statement works, it prints out all the minutes that user (or bnumber) corresponds to, instead of just printing out the set of minutes the user clicks on @Adam Link

Comment: At the minute the currentUser has 3 sets of minutes, i want to show and be able to edit these seperately, at the minute it shows and allows you to edit them all :S

Comment: As it is, your SQL statement will retrieve all the `Minutes` for that `B_number` and then iterate over them in the `while` loop that you have. To show just one `Minute` record, you'd have to change you SQL. I've updated my answer to include this.

Comment: changing the sql statement give these errors - 'Notice: Undefined variable: dbQuery

Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in viewstudentminutes.php on line 180'  . A student (Bnumber) can have many sets of minutes, i need it to show only the one clicked on

Comment: The change in the sql still throws errors :( 'Notice: Undefined variable: ID in viewstudentminutes.php on line 179  (My ID variable is defined?!)

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1' in viewstudentminutes.php:179 Stack trace: #0 viewstudentminutes.php(179): PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM `...') #1 {main} thrown in viewstudentminutes.php on line 179'

Comment: Can you update your code in the original question with the latest code you have or copy it to pastebin / gist? It is very difficult to debug where you are placing this code with just these comments.

Comment: THANK YOU!! it is bringing up just the set of minutes you click on, however it leads to another error when u click the edit button which was working before, its showing the following error (ps thank you very much for your help) error will follow in next comment

Comment: 'Notice: Undefined index: Minute_ID in viewstudentminutes.php on line 179
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1' in viewstudentminutes.php:179 Stack trace: #0 viewstudentminutes.php(179): PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM `...') #1 {main} thrown in viewstudentminutes.php on line 179'

Comment: You'll want to select this answer as the one that answered your question and likely open a new question for this new error with your new code. I'm not sure where this new error is coming from given the only code I have to go off of is older code.

Comment: The code above is what is giving the error when clicking on the 'edit.png' to edit the set of minutes